# Recommended value for the variable for Linear Congruential Generator

Tags: cryptography, random-seed, lcg

I am trying to generate 48 pseudoraandom number by using linear congruential generator. I am only using alphabet from a to z for my plaintext which will be for mapping 0 to 25.

I am using the algorithm for the linear congruential generator below

```
Xn+1 = (aXn + c) mod m
```

where Xn is the sequence of pseudorandom values, and

```
• Modulus: m, 0 < m
• Multiplier: a, 0 < a < m
• Increment: c, 0 ≤ c < m
• Seed: X0, 0 ≤ X0 < m
```

I am using the algorithm for the linear congruential generator below

```
Xn+1 = (aXn + c) mod m
X2 = (7(11) + 11) mod 18 = 16
X3 = (7(16) + 11) mod 18 = 15
X4 = (7(15) + 11) mod 18 = 8
```

What would be the recommended value for the seed, increment, multiplier and modulus. Keystream need to be from 0 to 26 as I need to map the number to the corresponding letter.
I want unique and less repetition.

Please kindly advise.

Thank you

Comment: Wikipedia gives some values [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

Comment: I am aware on the wikipedia link. I prefer a best value for best cipher

Comment: Using an LCG inevitably gives a weak cipher since LCGs are easily broken.  They are fine for a learning exercise, but not for real use.  For real use, research stream ciphers, or use a block cipher in counter (CTR) mode.

Comment: Yes I am aware. I want to use LCG for now to test it

Comment: The wikipedia article gives you all the information you need. There is no "best cipher" values because they're all bad. If you want to map ASCII letters to letters than you need values from 0 to 25, not 0 to 26. In that case you have your modulus, it's 26.